# SQL Server 2008 R2 match counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query that checks when a stored procedure was last run, from that date it gathers all the units that were purchased between that date and today's date and compares it to another number. If they match it sends an email saying the two number match and executes the rest of the stored procedure. However, when it runs I constantly get 0 for the number of accounts, when it should be a value greater than 0 daily:Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @UnitsPurchased  int
DECLARE @WelcomeLetterGenerated int
DECLARE @LastSuccesfulRunTime datetime 

SET @LastSuccesfulRunTime = (select cast(run_datetime as DATE) from apsllc_v2.dbo.LastSuccesfulRunDate)

SET @UnitsPurchased = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rsbi.dbo.loans as l 
    where rsbi.dbo.fn_Convert_Paradata_Birth_Date(l.Unit_PURDATE) between @LastSuccesfulRunTime
    AND  getDate() and l.LN_CLASS in (58,59)) -- Shows the number of units that were purchased yesterday

SET @WelcomeLetterGenerated = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apsllc_v2.dbo.ApsUpload ap where ap.FormNumber IN(1100,1150) ) -- Shows how many welcome letters were generated today

if  @UnitsPurchased <> @WelcomeLetterGenerated
begin 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                @recipients = N''
                , @body = ' '
                , @subject = 'Welcome Letter Counts do not Match'
                , @profile_name = 'Email_Profile_01'
                return
end         
ELSE if @UnitsPurchased = @WelcomeLetterGenerated --or if 
begin
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                      @recipients = N''
                    , @body = ' '
                    , @subject = 'Welcome Letter Counts  Match'
                    , @profile_name = 'Email_Profile_01'
end
```

Comment: Have you checked your fn_convert_paradata_birth_date function to verify that it works for the data being sent? Does rsbi.dbo.loans.unit_purdate return values that are valid for the function? What have you tested to ensure that the steps are working and to help isolate the cause?